# Exporting wireframe - freestyle not generating desirable output

Tags: rendering, wireframe, svg

I want to do a wireframe render of a model I created, however the freestyle renderer is proving to be of a low quality that ignores many outlines. Compare the two images below. The freestyle renderer simply does not cut it - I want a way to generate a very similar output to the bottom image which represents the model properly. Help is appreciated.

[image: Freestyle]

[image: Wireframe - this is the effect I want in svg form]

Comment: You could try explicitly marking the (coplanar?) edges as 'Freestyle', and including marked edges in the Line Set, so they can be picked up.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the notice! I've marked every face for freestyle and also played with a few settings including making Crease Angle extremely low (0.1d), checking all Edge Types, inclusive negation (under Face Marks), etc. The output is a bit better but not quite desirable. Results here: https://imgur.com/a/DANMpuQ

Comment: @RobinBetts Update: My apologies, I got the crease angle the wrong way round. This is the result with a value of 179.9d: https://imgur.com/a/ImVsGP0

Much better, but not quite there yet. Notably, some lines are missing from the thing on the bottom left. Text doesn't contribute to the freestyle and there are some weird lines showing up that shouldn't exist: https://imgur.com/a/XdcIlTE

Comment: I think you're going to have to share a representative sample on blend-exchange.com

Comment: @RobinBetts Sure! Here's the file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/gEbPm8BD - I have removed a few elements to keep it detached from the associated project but I hope this reflects the situation described above.

Comment: I _think_ the problem is logical.. the use of [Face Marks](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/view_layer/line_set.html#face-marks)  rather than Edge Marks, which behave more in the way you illustrate, I think. Example [here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/O1YYwxKD/) with some liberties taken to make WIP more visible. BTW You'll have to forgive me if I'm not quickly responsive today.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you, looks like that's done it. Result looks good and only needs a few manual tweaks. Cheers!